# Jquery draggable stops after IE AJAX refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-ajax, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a web page where I create images from text by clicking a button and add the image to a draggable div in  a parent div element. The div is in an update panel. The divs are draggable after this event. I have another button which saves the html temporarily and recreates the divs with their positions when i add another image->text. However after this event all the old divs lose thier drag property, the last div which has been added still retains the draggable property.

```
 $(".inner").live('mousedown', function() {
    $(this).draggable({
              containment: "#<%=divMain.ClientID%>",
        cursor: "move",
        stop: function(event, ui) {
             var position = $(this).position();
            $(this).css("top", position.top + 'px');
            $(this).css("left",position.left + 'px');
        }
    });
});
```

This is my current function. Please suggest ! This works perfectly in Firefox and chrome. Issue is only in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankyou for your suggestions, i found the solution, when I add the div dynamically through the ajax[postback], i destroy draggble for all divs which have been added.$('.draggable').draggable('destroy'); 
Then reassign the draggable function using the live function $(".draggable'").live('mousedown click', function() {...});
Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because jquery is losing its event after partial post backs. 
try using this way,

`function pageLoad()
{
$(".inner").live('mousedown', function() {     $(this).draggable({               containment: "#<%=divMain.ClientID%>",         cursor: "move",         stop: function(event, ui) {              var position = $(this).position();             $(this).css("top", position.top + 'px');             $(this).css("left",position.left + 'px');         }     }); }); 
}`

Comment: Thanks for that, I had tried that earlier but does not seem to work. I tried re-registering the function using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Test();", true);. but to no avail.

Comment: try to put your function inside Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestFunctionHandler);